# AutoResetEvent with Return Value

Tags: c#, autoresetevent

I am trying to implement an `AutoResetEvent` that returns a value when it is signaled with its Set method. I tried to use volatile on the `isCancelled` local variable but that resulted with a syntax error. I don't want to introduce a class field just for this method. So is there a way that I can both set that `AutoResetEvent` and get the boolean flag to know whether the operation is succeeded or not? Here is my code.

```
private async Task<bool> GetCancelOrderStatus(Pair pair)
{
    var autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    var isCancelled = false;

    var options = new SubscribeOptions(SubscribeOptionNames.CancelOrderStatus);
    var subscribe = new Subscribe(new[] { pair }, options);

    await _client.SubscribeAsync(subscribe);

    _client.CancelOrderStatusReceived += (sender, args) =>
    {
        if (args.Message.Status == Status.Ok)
            isCancelled = true;

        autoResetEvent.Set();
    };

    autoResetEvent.WaitOne();

    return isCancelled;
}
```

Comment: I thought that the local variable here might be cached in the register so we might get wrong results in the return statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample looks fine to me except for one thing: You're adding the event handler after waiting for the next subscription event. From here, I infer that `SubscribeAsync()` should cause `_client` to enter a state where `CancelOrderStatusReceived` might get fired; but if you attach the event handler after the await then you will probably miss the event.

Try inverting the two statements, and notwithstanding any other internal activity in `_client`, it should work.

```
private async Task<bool> GetCancelOrderStatus(Pair pair)
{
    var autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    var isCancelled = false;

    var options = new SubscribeOptions(SubscribeOptionNames.CancelOrderStatus);
    var subscribe = new Subscribe(new[] { pair }, options);

    _client.CancelOrderStatusReceived += (sender, args) =>
    {
        if (args.Message.Status == Status.Ok)
            isCancelled = true;

        autoResetEvent.Set();
    };

    await _client.SubscribeAsync(subscribe);

    autoResetEvent.WaitOne();

    return isCancelled;
}
```

Also, you might find that you don't even need the `AutoResetEvent` if the event `CancelOrderStatusReceived` is only fired during the time spent awaiting `SubscribeAsync` for this operation.

Comment: You are right, we should attach the event handler before we subscribe. But do you think a race condition can occur where `CancelOrderStatusReceived` fires before we call `WaitOne` on the `AutoResetEvent`. If this happends, a deadlock can occur because we never set the `AutoResetEvent` after calling `WaitOne`.

Comment: That should be fine, you're setting it in the event handler and there is no code visible here that could be affected between the event handler being appended and the ```WaitOne()``` call.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to implement an AutoResetEvent that returns a value when it is signaled with its Set method.

If you're using one kind of synchronization primitive and find yourself thinking "I want it to do something else", then that's an indication that the incorrect synchronization primitive is being used.

"`AutoResetEvent` with passing a value from `Set` to `Wait`" sounds to me like a producer/consumer queue, e.g., `BlockingCollection<T>`.

However, the code you posted is interesting. It ends up using a synchronous synchronization primitive from an asynchronous method, which raises a red flag. It seems to me that the `SubscribeAsync` + `CancelOrderStatusReceived` methods are a kind of Event-Based Asynchronous Pattern (EAP), and that the code would be made cleaner by [converting this to Task-Based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/interop-with-other-asynchronous-patterns-and-types#tasks-and-the-event-based-asynchronous-pattern-eap).